# Filtering XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transformation

I'm needing to filter which data is returned in my transform. Read my sample code and you will be able to see what I am trying to do here. I appreciate the help. Thanks.

```
<xsl:variable select="Records/Record[@level = '12345']/Field[@g = 'A67890']" name="Var1"/>
            <xsl:variable select="Records/Record[@level = '12345']/Field[@g = 'B67890]" name="Var2"/>
            <xsl:variable select="Records/Record[@level = '12345']/Field[@g= 'C67890']" name="Var3"/>
            <xsl:variable select="Records/Record/Record[@level = 'ABC']/Field[@g = 'D123']" name="Var4"/>
            <xsl:variable select="Records/Record/Record[@level = 'ABC']/Field[@g = 'C123']" name="Var5"/>
            <xsl:if test="(contains($Var1= 'And') and ($Var2 = $Var4) and ($Var3 = $Var5) or contains($Var3= 'Or')">


    ----------**Code that is ran after if test**

    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Please show your input XML and explain in plain English which conditions you want to check. I am afraid `contains($Var1= 'And')` is no meaningful XPath syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I am not authorized to post my input XML. I need to check if  Var1=And and if Var2=Var4 and Var3=Var5 or if Var1=Or. Does that help?

Comment: `contains($Var1, 'And')` would be the proper syntax for contains. Without some mock data at least, it's hard to tell what you are doing. Can you post some anonymized data?

Comment: All of my variables are returning correctly. I'm just not sure on the syntax for the if.

Comment: It would take me hours to anonymize my XML. So the code I posted above, is me declaring the variables above my transform then the if statement uses these variables to decide if the transform needs to be ran.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is the correct `if` syntax then:

```
<xsl:if test="(contains($Var1, 'And')
               and ($Var2 = $Var4)
               and ($Var3 = $Var5)
               or contains($Var3, 'Or')">


----------**Code that is ran after if test**

</xsl:if>
```

Comment: That ended up not working for me. I will try to get authorization to post source file because I may have a bigger problem.

Comment: Could I just be using the wrong approach entirely? The if is suppose to decide if the transform should be ran or not.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you are doing. The `contains` are checking if the contents of `$Var1` actually contain the string literal 'And' and `$Var3` 'Or'. Is this your intention? You can do all this without variables just using `<xsl:apply-templates />` and template matching, but that would be another question.

Comment: Okay, so the variables need to meet of 1 of the 2 criteria. 1. VAR1=And and VAR2=VAR4 and VAR3=VAR5. 2. VAR1=Or. If the input equals either of these then it needs to run the transform.